# USB devices never work if I unplug them once

Tags: windows-10, usb

I am having some problems with my USB devices. If I unplug any USB device once and then plug it again, it doesn't work at all. The only way to solve the problem is to restart the windows. What should I do?

I am using Windows 10 on an HP laptop. I have the following USB devices:

- Logitech K120 KEyboard
- A4Tech OP-6200 Mouse
- GrameenPhone 3G Modem

Comment: Do you eject the device before unplugging?